# ARCH boot error from USB:modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.15.5-2-ARCH/modules.deb, no such file or directory

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, installation, arch-linux

I am following the (32-bit) ARCH installation tutorial on

http://wideaperture.net/blog/?p=3851

This works fine on VirtualBox. No issues. However, when I repeat the process on a real hardware with USB drive (/dev/sdc is my USB - I replaced all instances of /dev/sdaX in the tutorial with /dev/sdcX ) I get the following errors

`modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.15.5-2-ARCH/modules.deb, no such
file or directory.`

Wondering what it could be? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Grub instead of syslinux by looking at the following guide http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/install-arch-linux-usb and now it worked fine. I also appended `acpi=off noacpi noapic` to all instances of `...vmlinumz...` in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`